# webview callback not working from android application

Tags: android, android-webview

I trying to set callback on webview but I failed to get response. Please help me I am new born in android.

Android code:-

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    // Javascript inabled on webview
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {@JavascriptInterface
        public void block(String encodeuserId,String encodeOtherUserId) {

            Log.d("Block::", "Clicked");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "User  have been blocked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:block()");
                }
            });
        }
    }, "Block");
    mWebView.evaluateJavascript("block();",null);

    mWebView.loadUrl(Url);
```

Web code: -

```
<button id="block-btn" class="block-btn" style="background-color: red" onclick="block(109589, 109587)">Block</button> </td> <td class="description-btn" style="padding:20px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick should reference method called on the interface. Since your interface name passed in `addJavascriptInterface` is `Block` you should call `Block.block()`.